# How can I use django-nvd3 to draw multi line chart with different values in X-axis?

Tags: django, python-3.x, nvd3.js

All the examples I could find in searches to draw several lines in graph such as:
https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3/blob/master/demoproject/demoproject/views.py#L66
use completely same values for x-axis. something like:

```
start_time = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 1).timetuple()) * 1000)
nb_element = 150
xdata = range(nb_element)
xdata = map(lambda x: start_time + x * 1000000000, xdata)
ydata = [i + random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(nb_element)]
ydata2 = map(lambda x: x * 2, ydata)

tooltip_date = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %p"
extra_serie1 = {
    "tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"},
    "date_format": tooltip_date,
    'color': '#a4c639'
}
extra_serie2 = {
    "tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " cal"},
    "date_format": tooltip_date,
    'color': '#FF8aF8'
}
chartdata = {'x': xdata,
             'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie1,
             'name2': 'series 2', 'y2': ydata2, 'extra2': extra_serie2}
```

What can I do when I want to draw two lines with these data (x values for two graph points are not completely the same):

```
xdata1 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
ydata1 = [18, 3, 5, 2]
xdata2 = [1, 3, 5, 6]
ydata2 = [3, 13, 0, 6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to inject datasets with different x-axis. NVD3 is a chart library and so doesn't put much complexity in processing data, so you need to normalize your x-axis.

If you have complex datasets you can look at Panda, it can help you normalizing your dataset when you have different x-axis, http://pandas.pydata.org/